# Write a query to determine all X1,X2 such that X1 and X2 have different values for D

Tags: sql, oracle

The first table (X) has columns X1 and X2.
The second table (Y) has columns X and D.
Both X1 and X2 have a foreign key constraint referring to column X in table Y.
Write a query to determine all X1,X2 such that X1 and X2 have different values for D.

---

I have tried following

```
SELECT x.*, y1.d, y2.d 
FROM x 
INNER JOIN y  y1 ON x.x1 = y1.X
INNER JOIN y  y2 ON x.x2 = y2.X 
WHERE y1.d <> y2.d;
```

[sample table data for X and Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17lHJ.jpg)

Comment: Sound like homework... we may help but you'll need to show us what you tried, where it don't work ...

Comment: @jordan7 . . . Your query looks correct.  What is the issue?

Comment: query runs fine, but i get no data in output it says "no data found" (i am using live oracle.com to perform this task)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have attached the sample data for table X and Y.

Comment: Your sample data will never generate any rows as the `X.X1` and `X.X2` values are always identical and will point to the same `Y.D` value and so your `WHERE` filter will exclude every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you not using a CASE-WHEN statement ?

```
(case when table1.x1 = d or table1.x2 = table2.d then 'No difference' 
 else 'Different value' END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated sub-queries to find the `D` values:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   X
WHERE  ( SELECT d FROM y WHERE y.x = x.x1 )
       <> ( SELECT d FROM y WHERE y.x = x.x2 );
```

So, if your data is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE X ( X1, X2 ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 5 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Y ( x, d ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> X1 | X2
> -: | -:
>  2 |  3
>  1 |  4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9653865de90c71811fb0b2e0e37ac38d)*

---

Your query works too; however, your test data doesn't work as you always have identical values for the `Y.D` value for both `X.X1` and `X.X2` so the `WHERE` clause will exclude every row. If you use different values then it works.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f8e3988acbda1929ed89e1a3b42894da)*

Comment: thank you so much, that was so silly of me not to check the data entered. thanks again.